# in the obnam backup software how do I set the sftp port?

Tags: sftp

I want to do the backup on a non default port. With the sftp command I can use `-P 1234` but the obnam software needs a path like so:

```
sftp://user@host/path/to/backup
```

Where can I add the sftp port?

Answer (score 0):

I found it in the docs:

```
sftp://[user@]domain[:port]/path
```